# EmbeddedCassandraServer getting "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

Tags: java, cassandra, server, pojo, cassandra-3.0

Im using Cassandra-Unit 3.1.3.2 for doing unit testing.

Below is my code snippet

```
EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.CASSANDRA_RNDPORT_YML_FILE);
    appConfig.setCassandraPort(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.getNativeTransportPort());
    appConfig.setCassandraSession(Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(InetAddress.getByName("localhost").getHostAddress())
        .withPort(54567).build().connect());
    CqlSchemaInitializer cqlSchemaInitializer = new CqlSchemaInitializer(Arrays.asList("create_keyspace.cql"));
    cqlSchemaInitializer.initialize(appConfig.getCassandraSession());
    appConfig.setCassandraLodgingCommerceContentDao(new CassandraLodgingCommerceContentDao(appConfig.getCassandraSession()));
```

appConfig is just the pojo which has setter/getter.
Im getting the below error,

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil.newEventLoopGroupInstance(NettyUtil.java:134)
>     ... 35 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
>   DEFAULT_MAX_PENDING_TASKS     at
>   io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.(EpollEventLoop.java:84)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.newChild(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:114)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:64)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:49)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:93)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:80)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:61)
>     ... 40 more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After adding the below dependency it got resolved

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.netty</groupId>
<artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
<version>4.0.44.Final</version>
```